# Inserting some text before and after

Tags: html, css

I need to inject some text before and after the `hey` characters.
I need a CSS only solution.

My html:

```
<span class="wsite-headline">
     <font size="5">hey</font>
     <br>
     <strong>dude</strong>
</span>
```

I already try this css:

```
.wsite-headline font:before { content "before";  }
.wsite-headline font:after { content "after";  }
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: You are missing colons between the `content` property and the value.

Comment: Use jquery .before and .after

Comment: you need to write `content: "before";` to make your css valid.

Answer (score 7):

Double `::` for the selector and your missing a single `:` after `content`

```
.wsite-headline font::before { content: "before";  }
```

(`<font>` is depreciated in HTML5, consider a `<span>` and CSS to define the size)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the opportunity to change the HTML. Only possible for me to change CSS.

Comment: well, it doesn't matter. Even if you don't change the HTML, this answer will solve your issues

Comment: The part that solves the problem is the addition of the colon (`:`) between the CSS property name and the CSS property value. The rest is irrelevant to the practical question.